# Draw GoogleMap path with 9patch

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently trying to draw a fairly stylised path onto a map.

Method as it stands

```
public ArrayList<Polyline> renderNeonPolyline(Context context,
                                                           ArrayList<LatLng> routeCoordinates,
                                                           GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ArrayList<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.width(48 - (i * 8));
        if (i == 0) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.apple_25));
        } else if (i == 1) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.apple_50));
        } else if (i == 2) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.apple_75));
        } else if (i == 3) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.apple));
        } else if (i == 4) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white_75));
        } else if (i == 5) {
            polylineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        }
        polylineOptions.addAll(routeCoordinates);
        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        polylines.add(polyline);
    }

    return polylines;
}
```

So this is working. It draws a nice line with a neon-y kind of effect... most of the time. For some reason there are certain circumstances where only the first apple_25 line gets rendered. (I think this has something to do with the fact that we're trying to zoom and pan the map at the same time, but haven't looked into it) Also, the ends look pretty rough.

What I was really hoping to do was draw a single line with a 9patch image.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may not completely solve your issue, but I think it's a good workarond.

You can use [richmaps](https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps) (I'm the owner of the project) to draw polylines on the map with a bitmap based stroke shader:

```
RichPolylineOptions polylineOpts = new RichPolylineOptions(null)
        .zIndex(3)
        .strokeWidth(35)
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.22987, -3.95931)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23109, -3.95926)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23063, -3.95837)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23169, -3.95809)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23093, -3.95705)))
        .add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23023, -3.95626)))
        .strokeShader(new BitmapShader(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourdrawable),
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT)); // Using a Bitmap as the stroke shader
RichPolyline polyline = polylineOpts.build();
polyline.add(new RichPoint(new LatLng(40.23163, -3.95602)).color(Color.CYAN)); // RichPoint added after the creation of the RichPolyline
richLayer.addShape(polyline);

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(40.23063, -3.95837), 18, 0, 0)));
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This could work! I'll give it a try this afternoon. Thanks

Comment: @antonio I have tried your library, but it does not draw any polylines or polygons at all. Is there some sort of trigger like start() or draw() method?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder you need to call `richLayer.refresh();` on the `onCameraChange` method (or on the `onCameraIdle` method)

Comment: @antonio Thank you! I figured it out. This is working well. Great library!